# FluentAssertions compile error after upgrade

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have upgraded my project to the latest FluentAssertions and got a weird compilation error on the following line:

```
myArray.Should().Equal(new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

The error is:

> 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Should' and no
>   extension method 'Should' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum .NET runtime supported by FA v3.0 is .NET 4.0.3 (which is .NET 4.0 Update 2). In other words, you need to re-target the unit test project to .NET 4.0.3. If you are using Visual Studio 2013, then you already have .NET 4.5 installed and that framework supersedes 4.0.3.

Comment: Just a heads up. In the upcoming release 3.1, thanks to the new Shared Projects feature of VS2012.3, we've re-enabled support for plain old .NET 4.0.